# Why is this for loop not working in my django template?

Tags: python, django

this is my views :

```
rooms = [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'room-1'},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'room-2'},
    {'id': 3, 'name': 'room-3'},
    {'id': 4, 'name': 'room-4'},
]

def rooms(request):
    return render(request, 'rooms.html', {'rooms': rooms})
```

and template codes :

```
{% for room in rooms %}
    <li>{{room.id}} -- {{room.name}}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

unfortunately for loop is not working.

Comment: what is `rooms` supposed to be? a function or a list?

Comment: when you define the view function `rooms` you used same name as your list var, so `rooms` now refers to the view function and not the list

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function "rooms" has the same name as the list "rooms".

Changing the function or list name can resolve the problem.